# Sass::SyntaxError Preventing Heroku Rails App from Precompiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm getting the following error message when I try to push my app to Heroku.  It says the rake is aborted because:

```
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...top: 4px solid ": expected ";", was "\  ;"
remote:        (sass):4367
```

The weird thing here is that if I search for `top: 4px solid` in the entire project, it doesn't appear. at all.  The error says `(sass):4367`, but I have no idea how to find that.

If it matters, I just finished upgrading from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.2.

Does anyone know a way to find where this is or fix it?

Comment: Try running the precompile task locally with `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile`, maybe it shows more info about the error.

Comment: @arieljuod Nope, unfortunately same exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, but on Rails 4.2.0. It's caused by a bug in sass 3.7.0 (which was released on the 6th of november). Either downgrading to 3.6.0 or upgrading to the new 3.7.1 release resolves the issue. Specifically, edit your Gemfile.lock and change:

```
sass (3.7.0) -> sass (3.7.1)
```

Alternatively you can run bundle update sass, which should now update it to 3.7.1 as well and it will automatically update your Gemfile.lock accordingly.

More information regarding the original bug: https://github.com/sass/ruby-sass/issues/94

Comment: Is this a change in Gemfile.lock? or gemfile? I can't seem to get it to stick....

Comment: Never mind, adding gem 'sass', '3.7.1' to gemfile seems to have solved it... 
gemlock seems to keep reverting to       sass (>= 3.3.4)...

Comment: I meant the lockfile, I'll update my answer to specifically list that. Alternatively you could now remove that gem from your Gemfile and simply run bundle update sass. It will update it to 3.7.1 and update your Gemfile.lock accordingly.

Comment: It was in fact an issue inside one of the gems.  No the sass one, but a different gem required redactor-rails, which had the bug inside it.